# $\sim p$ ,$\sim\sim\sim\sim\sim p$ , and $\sim\sim\sim\sim\sim\sim\sim\sim\sim\sim\sim\sim p$ . Which of these are equal?

Tags: boolean-algebra

I made an attempt on this question. Please guide me if its wrong.

Consider the following boolean fuctions: $\sim p$ ,$\sim\sim\sim\sim\sim p$  , and $\sim\sim\sim\sim\sim\sim\sim\sim\sim\sim\sim\sim p$  . Which of these are equal?

$\sim p$
   and $\sim\sim\sim\sim\sim p$
  are equal since if we write $\sim\sim p$,
  then this can be simplified to give $p$
  as double negation canceled out or we can say $\sim\sim p=p$.
 Thus, in $\sim\sim\sim\sim\sim p$,
  there are $2$ pairs of double negation ($\sim$)
  which cancel out leaving the answer to $\sim p$.
 If we compare $\sim p$
  and $\sim\sim\sim\sim\sim\sim\sim\sim\sim\sim\sim\sim p$, then
  we can say that they are not equal since $\sim\sim\sim\sim\sim\sim\sim\sim\sim\sim\sim\sim p$
  has $6$ pairs of double negations ($\sim$)
  which cancel out leaving the answer as only $p$.
 If we compare $\sim p$
  and $\sim\sim\sim\sim\sim\sim\sim\sim\sim\sim\sim\sim p$,
  then we again say that they are not equal, as shown above $\sim\sim\sim\sim\sim\sim\sim\sim\sim\sim\sim\sim p=p$.
 Thus, $\sim p$
  is not equal to $p$.

Comment: Yeah it looks right but notice that $ \neg^{(2k)}p = p \  \&  ~ \neg^{(2k + 1)}p = \neg p, \ \ k \in \mathbb N$. This can be proven by induction. This can probably save you a lot of writing.

Comment: Yes, your answer is correct.

Comment: Roneel: I just tried to clean up your question a bit. Did you type it on a phone or something? It looked very disorganized as it was inserted. Maybe  [this tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) will help more in the future if you have not seen it already. Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

We have the following (this is the clearest way to see it IMO):

- $\sim p\equiv\,\sim p$
- $\sim\sim\sim\sim\sim p\equiv\,\sim(\sim\sim(\sim\sim p))\equiv\,\sim p$
- $\sim\sim\sim\sim\sim\sim\sim\sim\sim\sim\sim\sim p\equiv (\sim\sim(\sim\sim(\sim\sim(\sim\sim(\sim\sim (\sim\sim p))))))\equiv p$

Hence, the first two are equal. Your answer is correct, as MJD has pointed out in a comment. The above is largely provided to give increased clarity.